# Magento 2: How to set custom validation message?

Tags: magento2, validation, messages

I want to change Magento 2 validation message with my custom message.
on product detail page if I click add to cart button without selecting options than its shows **This is a required field**. but I want to change it with my custom message like **Please select size**.

[image]

Can anyone help me with this?
Thanks for your answer in advance.

Comment: did you get any solution for this ?

Comment: no, i didnt get the solution

Answer (score 34):

Just go-to that input field and add a custom attribute "data-msg-required"

data-msg-(validator name)

Like..

```
<input name="qty" id="qty" class="input-text" type="text" data-validate='{"required":true}' data-msg-required="Please select size."/>
```

Comment: This worked for me.

Comment: This is the right way!

Comment: this is more proper way to change validation message

Comment: Great. It works like charm!

Comment: Superb!!!!!!!!!

Comment: translation is not working on google chrome browser

Answer (score 6):

I found this solution and worked for me

```
    require([
    'jquery',
    'jquery/ui',
    'jquery/validate',
    'mage/translate'
], function($){
    $("div#product-options-wrapper select").addClass("product-custom-option-required").removeClass("required");

    $.validator.addMethod(
        'product-custom-option-required', function (value) {
            if(value) return true;
            else return false;
        }, $.mage.__('Please select a variant!'));
});
```

I am adding class to select element **product-custom-option-required** and remove **required** class.
After that I put my custom validation and as you can see at the last row I put custom text for custom validation message.

Answer (score 5):

Here is the solution which worked for me to changing the message of password field. It might help you in your direction.I have created script rather than overriding entire validation.js. I have added new function and replace error with new. As magento2 is using jquery validation. I have taken this function from validation.js

```
require([
            'jquery',
            'jquery/ui',
            'jquery/validate',
            'mage/translate'
        ], function($){
            $('#password').attr('data-validate', $('#password').attr('data-validate').replace('validate-customer-password','validate-customer-password-custom'));
            $.validator.addMethod(
                'validate-customer-password-custom', function(v, elm) {
                var validator = this,
                    length = 0,
                    counter = 0;
                var passwordMinLength = $(elm).data('password-min-length');
                var passwordMinCharacterSets = $(elm).data('password-min-character-sets');
                var pass = $.trim(v);
                var result = pass.length >= passwordMinLength;
                if (result == false) {
                    validator.passwordErrorMessage = $.mage.__(
                        "Minimum length of this field must be equal or greater than %1 symbols." +
                        " Leading and trailing spaces will be ignored."
                    ).replace('%1', passwordMinLength);
                    return result;
                }
                if (pass.match(/\d+/)) {
                    counter ++;
                }
                if (pass.match(/[a-z]+/)) {
                    counter ++;
                }
                if (pass.match(/[A-Z]+/)) {
                    counter ++;
                }
                if (pass.match(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/)) {
                    counter ++;
                }
                if (counter < passwordMinCharacterSets) {
                    result = false;
                    validator.passwordErrorMessage = $.mage.__(
                        "Minimum of different classes of characters in password is %1." +
                        " Classes of characters: Lower Case, Upper Case, Digits, Special Characters."
                    ).replace('%1', passwordMinCharacterSets);
                }
                return result;
            }, function () {
                return this.passwordErrorMessage;
            });
        });
```

Here is more detail about this solution [on my own blog](https://blog.m2doctor.com/change-validation-custom-error-message-magento2/) and entire module for this [on my Github repository](https://github.com/m2doctor/Validation)

Comment: I used your module and it worked. However when I tried to do it in the validation.js itself it dint work. Any idea why it dint work?

Comment: @SejalShah Are you trying to change the validation.js directly ?

Comment: yes...I changed directly in validation.js just to check. I was goin to override it later

Comment: You can then go to validation js and change the class. Please notice that validation.js will also available in pub/static folder.

Comment: I just wanted to change the message. No need to change the class right ?

Comment: Yes , you are correct

Comment: You can give up vote if it helps you

Comment: Great Solution.Worked like a charm.