# Magento 2: Data validation message input field

Tags: magento2, validation, form-validation

I created an input box in Magento 2 and let the validator check the input value. That works perfect in the example below:

```
<input id="input-gleich-breite-0"
       class="maximum-length-4 validate-digits-range digits-range-200-1440"
       name="input-width-0"
       type="number"
       data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-number':true}"
       data-msg-required="Please input data between 200 and 1440"
       value="300">
```

Now I would like to check if the value is in between "200" and "1440". 
This should work with the following part of input:

```
data-msg-validate-number="Please input data between 200 and 1440"
```

But it doesn't work. It only works with the following and only checks for any data in the input box.

```
data-msg-required="Please input data between 200 and 1440"
```

The information are taken from [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/163585/magento-2-how-to-set-custom-validation-message).
I really appreciate any hint!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you could try is to add a JavaScript mixin:

In requirejs-config.js do:

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'mage/validation': {
                'Vendor_Module/js/validation-mixin': true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and Vendor_Module/view/frontend/web/js/validation-mixin.js:

```
define([
    'jquery'
], function ($) {
    "use strict";

    return function () {
        $.validator.addMethod(
            'digits-range-200-1440',
            function (value) {
                // Some custom validation stuff here
                return true or false;
            },
            $.mage.__('Please input data between 200 and 1440')
        );
    }
});
```

your input tag

```
<input id="input-gleich-breite-0"
       class="maximum-length-4 validate-digits-range digits-range-200-1440"
       name="input-width-0"
       type="number"
       data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-number':true}"
       value="300">
```